# `Error 403: Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB"` when creating kubernetes cluster with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hi I am playing around with kubernetes and terraform in a google cloud free tier account (trying to use the free 300$). Here is my terraform resource declaration, it is something very standard I copied from the terraform resource page. Nothing particularly strange here.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "${var.cluster-name}-${terraform.workspace}"
  location = var.region
  initial_node_count = 1
  project = var.project-id
  remove_default_node_pool = true
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "cluster_node_pool" {
  name       = "${var.cluster-name}-${terraform.workspace}-node-pool"
  location   = var.region
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.cluster.name
  node_count = 1

  node_config {
    preemptible  = true
    machine_type = "e2-medium"
    service_account = google_service_account.default.email
    oauth_scopes    = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    ]
  }
}
```

This terraform snippet used to work fine. In order to not burn through the 300$ too quickly, at the end of every day I used to destroy the cluster with `terraform destroy`.
However one day the kubernetes cluster creation just stopped working. Here is the error:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": request requires '300.0' and is short '50.0'. project has a quota of '250.0' with '250.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=xxxxxx., forbidden
```

It looks like something didn't get cleaned up after all the terraform destroy and eventually some quota built up and I am not able to create a cluster anymore. I am still able to create a cluster through the google cloud web interface (I tried only with autopilot, and in the same location). I am a bit puzzled why this is happening. Is my assumption correct? Do I need to delete something that doesn't get deleted automatically with terraform? if yes why? Is there a way to fix this and be able to create the cluster with terraform again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I think I figured out what's going. The crucial thing here is to understand the difference between [*zonal* and *regional* clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters#availability).

tldr; A zonal cluster operates in only zone, where a regional cluster may be replicated across multiple zones.

From the doc,

> By default, GKE replicates each node pool across three zones of the control plane's region

I think this is why we're seeing the requirement going to 300GB (3 * 100GB), where the `--disk-size` defaults to 100GB.

The solution is to set the `location` to a `zone` than a `region`. Of course, here I'm assuming a zonal cluster would satisfy your requirements. E.g.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "${var.cluster-name}-${terraform.workspace}"
  location = "us-central1-f"
  initial_node_count = 1
  project = var.project-id
  remove_default_node_pool = true
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "cluster_node_pool" {
  name       = "${var.cluster-name}-${terraform.workspace}-node-pool"
  location   = "us-central1-f"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.cluster.name
  node_count = 1

  node_config {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: amazing! that was indeed the issue! I am impressed how you could figure it out without actually seeing the content of my `var.region` variable! well done! and thank you!

Comment: Haha the variable name gave it away a bit plus you mentioned you used the terraforn example (which I also did). I just realized that you said the script used to work and one day suddenly stopped working. Interesting. Was it because you changed from a zone to a region at some point or I wonder if something in GCP changed?

Comment: I think I may inadvertently started using the variable or changed it, i don't remember exactly. Thank you!

Comment: please note that this config is set to zonal: `location = "us-central1-f"` which I think region is better option for production.
And `location = us-central1` still work. You should set `node_config` (in `google_container_node_pool`) with  `disk_size_gb` for example to 10 Gi to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the disk type from SSD(default) to Standard Persistent Disk makes it work:

```
--disk-type pd-standard
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue that was resolved by moving my clusters to a different region.
You can view the quotas for a region by replacing `$PROJECT-ID$` with your project-id `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=$PROJECT-ID$` 
and heading to that link.

If you filter the list to `persistent disk ssd (GB)` you should see a list of all the available regions along with their quotas.

[image: Filter to persistent disk ssd (gb)]

Hope that helps.

[image]

Otherwise, your best bet is to request a quota increase for the region you desire.

Comment: it is everywhere zero under usage. Also switching zone will eventually run out of zones?

Comment: @DarioB not sure I completely understand your comment. The error you're receiving indicates that the zone/region you're in has a limit of 250 GB and you need at least 300 GB to start up a cluster. In my screenshots, you can see that the zone asia-east2-a has a cap of unlimited so I would probably be able to spin up my cluster there.

Comment: ah! you are right. Maybe I could change some config like the machine type? I wonder why it was working before. I am quite sure I was using the same configuration.

Comment: @DarioB did this solve your issue?

Comment: no unfortunately it didn't work. I tried specifying both `machine_type = "e2-micro"` and `machine_type = "n1-standard-1"` and got the same error message. The only way I could get it to work so far is by using the autopilot mode.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Compute Engine > Disks, and check if there are any disks in the specified region which is consuming the quota.

This error says that the request will require 300GB of SSD and you have a quota of 250 GB in that region. This error generally occurs when the quota is [exhausted](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters#pricing). You can read more about the type of disk quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#disk_quota). You can also [request a quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#about_increase_requests) if you want.

I am not able to understand why this request needs 300 GB of SSD as I am not quite familiar with Terraform. From the code, it seems that you are creating only one node. As per the [terraform doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#nested_node_config), the "disk_size_gb" defaults to 100GB. So, it should take only 100 GB. Try to set a smaller size in the "disk_size_gb" in "node_config" and check if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, (Un)fortunately I don't have any disk created in any region. Hence I am afraid it is not that. I will try create the cluster in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by creating the cluster in autopilot mode using `enable_autopilot = true` rather than manually creating the node_pool (through terraform) and letting google take care of that. However I am afraid that I may have just hidden the problem under the carpet as the cluster may be initially created with a small disk and then it gets scaled up as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue today while trying to create the standard cluster at GCP Portal itself, noted the error message below:

```
Create Kubernetes Engine cluster cluster-1-standard
5 hours ago
My First Project
**Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": request requires '300.0'** and is short '50.0'. project has a quota of '250.0' with '250.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=ecstatic-splice-400311.
```

However after I read thru this post, realized a way to cut down (i.e. less than 300gb) the total size being requested as a workaround. So to do that,

1. Navigate to Node Pools below cluster basics on left hand dash menu.
2. Drop down option default-pool, select Nodes
3. Now on under "Configure node settings", set the Boot disk size from 100GB default to anything like 75Gb, so that total i.e. 75*3 comes down within free quota. Hence 225 in this case below quota of 250gb[cluster with mode - standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La7DR.png)
4. Clicked Create cluster and cluster was created with no other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Keep cluster in region is better option ( compared with zonal).
To scale down disk use ( default is 100Gi for 1 instance).
We can set in node_pool config:

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "general" {
  # Other config

  node_config {
    machine_type = var.machine_type
    disk_size_gb = 10 # This will set to 10 instead of 100
  }
  
  # Other config
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "${var.cluster-name}-${terraform.workspace}"
  location = "us-central1-f"
  initial_node_count = 1
  project = var.project-id
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  node_config {
    disk_size_gb = "20"
  }
}
```

add a node_config {} with disk_size_gb which will not exceed when you multiply by 3 will solve the problem if you use a regional cluster. You really don't need to stick with zonal cluster for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna create  Kubernetes cluster using standard configuration then make sure you have selected maximum number of nodes as 2 or less only. You need to check "Node pool details".
To change or check that follow below steps:

1. Create Cluster
2. Select Standard and click configure
3. Provide cluster name , location of your choice and etc things.
4. On the left panel locate "**NODE POOLS**" and click on "default-pool"
5. Locate or search on the browser page "Number of nodes". You will find text box to add number of nodes. In your case it must more than 2 nodes that's why you are getting error.
   Other option is to increase the Limit of your desired region and that may need approval from Google as per new policy.

Comment: since I am trying to create the cluster through terraform, what terraform configuration should I use to achieve what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue (note that this was not for production and it was just for my study/hands-on practice purpose). Rather than bothering about quota, I just reduced the disc-size (--disk-size "20") as I was "okay" with it since I was just working for study purpose. Below command-line worked for me.

```
gcloud beta container --project "ace-exam-kubernetes-engine" clusters create "my-kubernetes-cluster-1" --no-enable-basic-auth --cluster-version "1.27.3-gke.100" --release-channel "regular" --machine-type "e2-medium" --image-type "COS_CONTAINERD" --disk-type "pd-balanced" --disk-size "20" --metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" --num-nodes "3" --logging=SYSTEM,WORKLOAD --monitoring=SYSTEM --enable-ip-alias --network "projects/ace-exam-kubernetes-engine/global/networks/default" --subnetwork "projects/ace-exam-kubernetes-engine/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default" --no-enable-intra-node-visibility --default-max-pods-per-node "110" --security-posture=standard --workload-vulnerability-scanning=disabled --no-enable-master-authorized-networks --addons HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,GcePersistentDiskCsiDriver --enable-autoupgrade --enable-autorepair --max-surge-upgrade 1 --max-unavailable-upgrade 0 --binauthz-evaluation-mode=DISABLED --enable-managed-prometheus --enable-shielded-nodes --node-locations "us-central1-c" --zone "us-central1-c"
```

Note : This was a "Standard" cluster and not "Autopilot" cluster.